# Array.filter() returning empty array although condition is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use filter to create a new array coming from firebase-firestore

this is the filter function- when console loging the result of `myTweet.userId === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` it returns true.

```
  isEqualToMyTweets = (myTweet) => {
        console.log(myTweet.userId)
        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        console.log(myTweet.userId === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        return myTweet.userID == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    }
```

yet when calling the function it returns an empty array:

```
    onListenForTweets() {
        this.unsubscribe = firebase.firestore()
            .collection('tweets')
            .orderBy('date', 'desc')
            .limit(this.state.limit)
            .onSnapshot((snap) => {
                const tweets = snap.docs.map(docs =>
                    ({ ...docs.data(), id: docs.id })
                   
                );
                this.setState({ tweets })

                let myTweets = tweets.filter(this.isEqualToMyTweets);               
            });
    }
```

the reason I'm doing this is that i want to introduce a condition and accordingly present the tweets of a certain user.

this is the components code:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tweets: [],
            loading: false,
            profile: "",
            interval: null,
            limit: 10,
        };
        this.myTweets = []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.onListenForTweets()
    }

    isEqualToMyTweets = (myTweet) => {
        console.log(myTweet.userId)
        console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        console.log(myTweet.userId === firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        return myTweet.userID == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    }

    onListenForTweets() {
        this.unsubscribe = firebase.firestore()
            .collection('tweets')
            .orderBy('date', 'desc')
            .limit(this.state.limit)
            .onSnapshot((snap) => {
                const tweets = snap.docs.map(docs =>
                    ({ ...docs.data(), id: docs.id })
                   
                );
                this.setState({ tweets })
                let myTweets = tweets.filter(this.isEqualToMyTweets);
                console.log(myTweets)
            });
    }

    async handleOnNewTweet(newTweet) {
        await firebase.firestore()
            .collection('tweets')
            .add(newTweet)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    }
```

this is an example of the console.log

```
TweetRoom.jsx:38 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:39 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:40 true
TweetRoom.jsx:38 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:39 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:40 true
TweetRoom.jsx:38 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:39 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:40 true
TweetRoom.jsx:38 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:39 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:40 true
TweetRoom.jsx:38 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:39 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:40 true
TweetRoom.jsx:38 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:39 c1btNa39vZe3ptPfuYUn2chUsAn1
TweetRoom.jsx:40 true
TweetRoom.jsx:56 []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: `let myTweets = tweets.filter(this.isEqualToMyTweets);` this saves the returned filtered array in a **local** variable to the callback. Outside of `onListenForTweets` that line of code will have no effect.

Comment: thanks for the response, what i want to do is a condition inside the func-

if(something){setState({tweets : myTweets})}

but the filter func is returning an empty array...

Comment: It would help to see the code you're using to call that function `onListenForTweets`. If you can post that code as well, or rather the code right before that `myTweets = tweets.filter()` line, we can work with that to see how the filter is working.

Comment: Try removing `this` from your filter, as it may be confusing the window's `this` with your function's `this`. Try this: `tweets.filter(isEqualToMyTweets);`

Comment: Can you add an example of all the `console.log` results from your `onListenForTweets` function?

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell the this is necessary because I'm using a class component

Comment: In the final comparison you write `myTweet.userID` whereas you where logging before `myTweet.userId`. I suppose there is no `userID` thus the comparison always fails, thus you get an entirely empty array.

Comment: thanks, @PeterSeliger that seemed to be the problem

Comment: Nope, this **is** and hopefully now **was** *obviously* the single point of failure ;-)

Comment: It's often the little things. Good catch @PeterSeliger. I used to get tripped by with `getElementById()` vs. `getElementByID()` all the time.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't forget to handle errors for the [`onSnapshot` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#optional-error:-error:-firestoreerror-=-void). This will save future head scratching when the tweets aren't loading

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki as this solution was pointed out in the comments to this thread by @PeterSeliger.

The issue is being caused by the final call of your `isEqualToMyTweets` function where you are calling `myTweet.userID` instead `myTweet.userId` without the final capital letter, thus the comparison always fails and you get an entirely empty array as a result.

So changing it to `myTweet.userId` will solve the issue.